# Serializing an object containing a Bitmap i .NET Compact Framework

Tags: serialization, compact-framework

I am writing a project for Windows mobile 6 (.NET CF 3.5). My project contains a class that looks like this:

```
class MyClass {
    private Bitmap picture;
    //... and some other fields ...

    public MyClass ()
    {
        picture = new Bitmap (/*Picture file path*/);
        //...
    }
}
```

To my surprise, I found out that there is no binary formatter in the .NET CF. Does anyone know how can I serialize such object??
I tried to use [CompactFormatterPlus](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CF_serializer.aspx) - but it didnt worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to attack this.

1. Manually serialize it.  The Bitmap class has [a Save method that can output to a Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142147.aspx).  You could send that to your serialization stream.
2. Use a third-party option.  I'd likely use [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and sorry for my late response. I tried to use three different third-party solutions, but non of them worked because the Bitmap class doesnt have a a default C'tor, which leaves me with your first option - to write my own class serializer. Could you give me some more info? I know I need to implement the  Iserializable interface, but I still cant understand how to use the Bitmap.Save() method. Can you please write me a small code snapshot?
Thanks again!